# Why console.log shows everything, and prints only one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
  let suit = ["spade", "club", "diamond", "heart"];
  let value = [
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "J",
    "D",
    "K",
    "T",
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
      let card = [];
      card.push(value[i] + suit[j]);
      console.log(card);
      $("h1").html(card);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You reset the `card` array every single iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please clarify what output you would have expected, why you thought would do that, and what happens instead. You can [edit] your question to include additional information.

Comment: and anyway, I want to make it to show how many cards in the deck, and then, by ever splitting the numbers, it is reflected and rendered html.. But I'll figure it out, just somehow, I was stuck in this place. If you're going to have a lack of patience again, I'll turn here.. But thank you very much, I'm starting, so I'll probably get you bored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new Array for each card, by declaring inside both loops. Instead, create it before running your loops. You were also overwriting the `h1`'s HTML every time with the current card in your loop. You might want to wait for the loop to complete before doing that:

```js
$(function () {
  const suit  = ["spade", "club", "diamond", "heart"],
        value = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","D","K","T"],
        cards = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
      cards.push(value[i] + suit[j]);
    }
  }
  // .join(' ') creates a String from your Array, joining the card names with a space
  $("h1").html(cards.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Big Thanks you blex .. and anyway, I want to make it to show how many cards in the deck, and then, by ever splitting the numbers, it is reflected and rendered html.. But I'll figure it out, just somehow, I was stuck in this place. If you're going to have a lack of patience again, I'll turn here..